# How to debug async, Task or Threaded c# code liner way in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, async-await, visual-studio-2019, task-parallel-library

I have legacy application and I want to debug the program line by line in c#. Whenever debugger reached inside async or Task method it started bumping around the sub method. Of course it used multi threaded environment but I want to debug them line by line to find the actual cause of defect.

Is there any way where we could slightly change our code to debug liner way ? How about Lock(obj) ?

Basically I want to restrict my program to use only single thread to debug my whole application.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/how-do-i-debug-async-code-in-visual-studio/ 
I been following this  article, but article itself bouncing to me.

Comment: You can freeze threads, that's making debugging easier. Let VS show the Threads and Task windows from the Debug menu, in both if them you can freeze and thaw the corresponding threads by right clicking them.